# why left join and inner join returns same result

Tags: mysql

```
branch_id   branch_name
1       Branch A
2       Branch B

user_id username    branch_id
1   abc     1
2   def     1
3   ghi     2
4   jkl     1
5   lmn     2
6   opq     2
```

query 1

```
query1="select a.branch_id,b.branch_id,a.branch_name from branch a LEFT JOIN user_mast b on a.branch_id=b.branch_id";
```

query 2

```
$query2="select a.branch_id,b.branch_id,a.branch_name from branch a INNER JOIN user_mast b on a.branch_id=b.branch_id";
```

**WHY LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN results are same.**

Comment: what difference were you expecting?

Comment: You ask 'WHY LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN results are same' But you do in code LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN

Comment: like here i am new to joins so how a new user will decide which join type to use if both Inner and Left and giving similar results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `RIGHT JOIN` in query 2. The reason why `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` results are the same is because all the records of table `branch` has at least one match on table `user_mast`.

The main difference between `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` is that `LEFT JOIN` still displays the records on the the `LEFT` side even if they have no match on the `RIGHT` side table.

## [SQLFiddle Demo (*the difference*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51aad/2)

Comment: what if i just want to display only 2 records branch a and branch b matching table b

Comment: Can you expand your question more? There could be many possible solution, `LIMIT`, `GROUP`, or possibly `DISTINCT` depending on what you want. Can you give me sample result?

Comment: like table a is branch master and table b is all users. Table a has 2 records and table b has 10 records. And i want i should only display 2 records as table a has 2 records but show table b fields also which matches table a values.

Comment: ok, so you need to group the records by their `branch_ID`. Example of this [click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51aad/6), I used `MIN` aggregate function. It returns the record which has the minimum `username` value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this it will help a lot in understanding JOINs

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: I found this being very straight forward explanation :-)

Comment: but no one has explained if the table b has multiple records

Comment: how can i just get 2 records using join like branch a and branch b exist in table b

Answer (score 0):

since your left table has the 2 records and right table has only 2 matching records. So it will fetch the same result as join in case of left join in this scenario.If you interchange the tables then you will know the use of left join.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the branch_id    from left table matching with branch_id   of right table

Comment: what if i just want to display only 2 records branch a and branch b matching table b